# Search folder inside 'appdata' folder

Tags: objective-c, google-drive-api

Trying to check folder exists in 'appdata' folder before creating one. Hence I do get file.list with following code:

```
GTLQueryDrive *folderExistsQuery = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesList];
folderExistsQuery.q =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed=false  and 'appdata' in parents and title='%@'",folderName];
```

The result is an error.Strange thing When I remove either `'appdata' in parents` or `title='%@'` options in the query I don't get any error. Someone could you please explain whats going wrong here?

Any modification to solution are also welcome.

**Edit**
Printing description of error:

```
Error Domain=com.google.GTLJSONRPCErrorDomain Code=500 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Internal Error)" UserInfo=0x1030d5c00 {error=Internal Error, NSLocalizedFailureReason=(Internal Error), GTLStructuredError=GTLErrorObject 0x10308d890: {message:"Internal Error" data:[1] code:500}}
```

Comment: What's your auth scope?

Comment: @BurcuDogan Scope is: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with queries that contain title and parents on `drive.appdata` and `drive.file` scope. You can either add `drive.readonly.metadata` temporarily if we're not breaking your installed apps. The fix has been pushed back, but I'm trying to make sure we're fixing it as soon as possible.

Another similar issue: [Error when listing files with query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17543738/error-when-listing-files-with-query/17554573#17554573)

Comment: Luckily My App is not yet out. Hoping that you guys fix it soon.

Comment: I had encountered similar error during appdata file updating (Not file searching) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23707388/unable-update-file-store-in-appdata-scope-500-internal-server-error Do you think the issues is closely related? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In current version of API to get list of files in application folder `spaces` property is used:

```
GTLQueryDrive * query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesList];
query.q = @"mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed = false";
query.spaces = @"appDataFolder";
```