# Error when listing files with query

Tags: google-drive-api

When I try to retrieve a folder by listing with differents query criterias, in Python, I get an error `HTTP 500 "Internal error"`.

The code to request the folder is the following:

`q = ["'root' in parents", "title='test'", "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'", "trashed=false"]
default_folder_list = service.files().list(q=' and '.join(q), fields="items/id").execute()`

If I remove the title or the parents criteria, it works. If I try with the [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v2/drive.files.list), it also works perfectly.
My app has only the `drive.file` permission.

What could be the origin of this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a known issue with `drive.file` scope, use `drive.readonly.metadata` additionally for queries.

Edit: It looks like the query is also broken with `drive.appdata` scope. I'm making sure that we're fixing it as soon as possible.

Comment: No link externally available, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the insight Burcu, it works. However, it is very annoying to ask for a new permission to already authentified users.

Can you give us more visibility on the resolution of this issue please?

Comment: It's a temporary solution, we will be fixing the drive.file scope issue but cant ship it as a hotfix at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

G recommends that your app should backoff and retry 500 errors. Did you try this and does it persistently fail on the retry?

Comment: Yes I actually do exponential backoff when requesting. Thanks for suggesting!

Answer (score 0):

I'm finding the same issue, and it has nothing to do with backing off or waiting... The API explorer works perfectly, but a URL in the next tab, developed from the explorer, fails every time. Not often... always!

The issue seems to be related to the query being more complex than a single item. e.g. if I ask for name= or something in parent then it works. If I combine both with "and" then it fails.

For example:

https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=%270B0ap0WDOII5mbjdwajNBMlRoZUU%27+in+parents&key={my key}

works fine, but

https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=%270B0ap0WDOII5mbjdwajNBMlRoZUU%27+in+parents+and+name%3D%27test.TXT%27&key={my key}

fails with

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "internalError",
    "message": "Internal Error"
   }
  ],
  "code": 500,
  "message": "Internal Error"
 }
}
```

Note that both of those URLs are copied directly from the "API's Explorer" section of 
https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list
with my API key added to the end of each.

It also fails in exactly the same way with the v2 interface.

Could there be a bug in the API? Having to do with files in a public folder?