# Using the " 'appdata' in parents " query throws a 500 internal server error

Tags: android, google-drive-api

Within my android app I'm searching for a file located in the appdata folder. I'm following these instructions: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=UiTHG_yl-jA#t=874

My code is as follows:

```
com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Files.List request = gDriveService.files().list();
request.setQ( "'" + getAppDataFolderId() + "' in parents AND title = '" + title + "'");
List<File> files = request.execute().getItems();
```

As soon as the query is being executed in my app (line 3), the "500 internal server error" exception is thrown. When I change the query as shown below everything is working.

```
request.setQ( "title = '" + title + "'");
```

In the questions below the answer is provided to add the DriveScopes.DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY scope. This does however not solve the issue (the same exception is still thrown).

[Error when listing files with query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17543738/error-when-listing-files-with-query/17554573#17554573)

[Search folder inside 'appdata' folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527933/search-folder-inside-appdata-folder)

How can I use the 'appdata' in parents query?

Comment: Are you using `drive.appdata` scope?

Comment: Yes that is correct, I'm assuming that this will mean that files().list() will automatically return only the files inside the appdata folder and that the query for 'appdata' in parents is therefore useless? Is this assumption correct?

Comment: There is a bug with appdata scopes and filtering by parent and title. Is it possible for you to temporarily add `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly.metadata` to your scopes?

Comment: I will use this for now. Development is still in progress and the app has not yet been released so it's currently no problem to add this scope. Do you have any indication on when this will be resolved?