# Unable update file store in appdata scope - 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: java, google-drive-api

Previously, I have a set of Google Drive API code, which works fine in the following scenarios

1. Save new file to appdata
2. **Update previous file in appdata**
3. Save new file to non-appdata
4. Update previous file in non-appdata

Few days ago, I encounter scenario 2 no longer work (Update previous file in appdata), whereas other scenarios still work without problem. I will be getting the following exception.

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 500 Internal Server Error
{
  "code": 500,
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "global",
      "message": "Internal Error",
      "reason": "internalError"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Internal Error"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:423)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
    at org.yccheok.jstock.gui.Utils.updateFile(Utils.java:1414)
```

I'm using both `DRIVE` and `DRIVE_APPDATA` scope - [authorizeDrive()](https://github.com/yccheok/jstock/blob/master/src/org/yccheok/jstock/google/Utils.java#L142)

The code is as follow

- [saveToGoogleDrive() - Save or update file in appdata](https://github.com/yccheok/jstock/blob/master/src/org/yccheok/jstock/gui/Utils.java#L1317), **doesn't work during update file**. Work during saving new file.
- [saveToLegacyGoogleDrive() - Save or update file in non-appdata](https://github.com/yccheok/jstock/blob/master/src/org/yccheok/jstock/gui/Utils.java#L1324), all works!

Exception is being thrown at Line 1414, which is

```
com.google.api.services.drive.model.File updatedFile = service.files().update(fileId, file, mediaContent).setNewRevision(false).execute();
```

Searching previous file in appdata using query `title contains 'jstock-fe78440e-e0fe-4efb' and trashed = false and 'appdata' in parents` is completely fine. We're able to retrieve the previous file id without problem.

However, `500 Internal Server Error` is being thrown, when we perform file updating using retrieved file id.

Some users encountered problem during searching in appdata (which is not my case). [Search folder inside 'appdata' folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527933/search-folder-inside-appdata-folder) The suggested workaround is to add `drive.readonly.metadata`. I had tried that once, but it makes no difference.

---

## Update

An excellent workaround proposed by [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)

> I've managed to reproduce the issue. Without setNewRevision(false) it
>   works - I realize that may not be feasible in all cases, but is it a
>   reasonable workaround for you for the moment?

However, I will on hold on such workaround at this moment. We prefer to have `setNewRevision(false)`, to prevent from causing increased use of the user's data storage quota - http://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update

---

**Short but complete source code to demonstrate the problem**

1. Create a client id & secret key. Update source code.
2. Create a `document.txt`
3. Run the source code **first time**, to upload `document.txt` to `appdata` folder. It should success. Check your uploaded file through online Google Drive. (Please refer to attachment)
4. Run the source code for **second time**, to perform update on previous `document.txt` in `appdata` folder. The `500 Internal Server Error` exception should be thrown.

[image]

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package insert;

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleTokenResponse;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.FileContent;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.FileList;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.ParentReference;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;


public class Insert {

    private static com.google.api.services.drive.model.File searchFromGoogleDrive(Drive drive, String qString) {
        try {
            Drive.Files.List request = drive.files().list().setQ(qString);

            do {                
                FileList fileList = request.execute();

                com.google.api.services.drive.model.File file = null;

                for (com.google.api.services.drive.model.File f : fileList.getItems()) {

                    final String title = f.getTitle();

                    if (title == null || f.getDownloadUrl() == null || f.getDownloadUrl().length() <= 0) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    file = f;

                    break;
                }

                if (file != null) {
                    return file;
                }

                request.setPageToken(fileList.getNextPageToken());
            } while (request.getPageToken() != null && request.getPageToken().length() > 0);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            log.error(null, ex);
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static boolean saveToGoogleDrive(Credential credential, java.io.File file) {
        final String titleName = "document.txt";
        final String qString = "title contains '" + titleName + "' and trashed = false and 'appdata' in parents";        
        return _saveToGoogleDrive(credential, file, qString, "appdata");
    }

    public static Drive getDrive(Credential credential) {
        Drive service = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName("JStock").build();
        return service;
    }

    private static boolean _saveToGoogleDrive(Credential credential, java.io.File file, String qString, String folder) {
        Drive drive = getDrive(credential);

        // Should we new or replace?

        com.google.api.services.drive.model.File googleCloudFile = searchFromGoogleDrive(drive, qString);

        final String title = "document.txt";

        if (googleCloudFile == null) {
            String id = null;
            if (folder != null) {
                com.google.api.services.drive.model.File appData;
                try {
                    appData = drive.files().get(folder).execute();
                    id = appData.getId();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    log.error(null, ex);
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return null != insertFile(drive, title, id, file);
        } else {
            final com.google.api.services.drive.model.File oldFile = googleCloudFile;
            return null != updateFile(drive, oldFile.getId(), title, file);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Insert new file.
     *
     * @param service Drive API service instance.
     * @param title Title of the file to insert, including the extension.
     * @param parentId Optional parent folder's ID.
     * @param mimeType MIME type of the file to insert.
     * @param filename Filename of the file to insert.
     * @return Inserted file metadata if successful, {@code null} otherwise.
     */
    private static com.google.api.services.drive.model.File insertFile(Drive service, String title, String parentId, java.io.File fileContent) {
        // File's metadata.
        com.google.api.services.drive.model.File body = new com.google.api.services.drive.model.File();
        body.setTitle(title);

        // Set the parent folder.
        if (parentId != null && parentId.length() > 0) {
            body.setParents(
                Arrays.asList(new ParentReference().setId(parentId)));
        }

        // File's content.
        FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("", fileContent);
        try {
            com.google.api.services.drive.model.File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();
            return file;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error(null, e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Update an existing file's metadata and content.
     *
     * @param service Drive API service instance.
     * @param fileId ID of the file to update.
     * @param newTitle New title for the file.
     * @param newFilename Filename of the new content to upload.
     * @return Updated file metadata if successful, {@code null} otherwise.
     */
    private static com.google.api.services.drive.model.File updateFile(Drive service, String fileId, String newTitle, java.io.File fileContent) {
        try {
            // First retrieve the file from the API.
            com.google.api.services.drive.model.File file = service.files().get(fileId).execute();

            // File's new metadata.
            file.setTitle(newTitle);

            FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("", fileContent);

            // Send the request to the API.
            com.google.api.services.drive.model.File updatedFile = service.files().update(fileId, file, mediaContent).setNewRevision(false).execute();

            return updatedFile;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error(null, e);
            return null;
        }
    }

  private static String CLIENT_ID = "CLIENT_ID";
  private static String CLIENT_SECRET = "CLIENT_SECRET";

  private static String REDIRECT_URI = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {   
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
        httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE_APPDATA, DriveScopes.DRIVE))
        .setAccessType("online")
        .setApprovalPrompt("auto").build();

    String url = flow.newAuthorizationUrl().setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI).build();
    System.out.println("Please open the following URL in your browser then type the authorization code:");
    System.out.println("  " + url);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String code = br.readLine();

    GoogleTokenResponse response = flow.newTokenRequest(code).setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI).execute();
    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential().setFromTokenResponse(response);

    java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File("document.txt");
    saveToGoogleDrive(credential, fileContent);
  }

    private static final GsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    /** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
    private static HttpTransport httpTransport;


    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(Insert.class);

    static {
        try {
            // initialize the transport
            httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            log.error(null, ex);
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException ex) {
            log.error(null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

### Update on 1 January 2016

This problem seems gone. I guess Google Drive team had fixed it.

Comment: Can you post a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem? (Without API keys etc, of course - but an obvious place to put them.)

Comment: I have some similar issue, but with different client. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23734503/drive-file-update-error-500)

Comment: @JonSkeet I had updated the question with a minimal workable. Please let me know, if you face any problem in re-producing the problem using the same source code. Thank you.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng: Thanks, will give it a go. (Can't you make it smaller my removing the `searchFromGoogleDrive` bit and just asking the user which mode to run in though?)

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you. I feel extremely honor to have you looking at my question :)

Comment: @JonSkeet Hem... I'm not sure how I can remove `searchFromGoogleDrive `. Without perform search functionality, I cannot retrieve the previous uploaded file id, and can't perform "update on previous file" operation.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng: Ah, okay - that's fair enough then.

Comment: @JonSkeet In short, the logic of the code is, if this is the first time, it will perform new file `insert`. If the file is already in `appdata` folder, it will perform content `update`.

Comment: I've managed to reproduce the issue. Without `setNewRevision(false)` it works - I realize that may not be feasible in all cases, but is it a reasonable workaround for you for the moment?

Comment: Thank you! However, we prefer have `setNewRevision(false)`, to prevent from causing increased use of the user's data storage quota - https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update But, if that's the only workaround, we will need to adapt such.

Comment: @JonSkeet Do you want to post your proposal as answer? I will wait for few more days, to see is there a better workaround, without compromising user's data storage quota.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Note: please do not treat this as an "official answer from Google". Although I work at Google, I don't work on the Drive API.

I've reproduced the problem, and reported it to the Drive API team, who *may* be able to provide more details. In the meantime, one workaround I've found is to remove the

```
setNewRevision(false)
```

part of your `update` call on line 1414. That's not an ideal workaround as it means you'll get a new revision for each update, which will use up storage quota. However, it does seem to avoid the problem you've seen.